# Spacy Phrase Matcher space sensitive issue

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

```
terms = ["Barack Obama", "Angela Merkel", "Washington, D.C."]
doc = nlp("German Chancellor Angela Merkel and US President Barack  Obama "
      "converse in the Oval Office inside the White House in Washington, D.C.")
```

If I enter an extra space between the words "Barack Obama", the phrase matcher does not work since it is space sensitive.
Is there a way to overcome this space sensitive issue?

- Operating System: Windows 8
- Python Version Used: 3.7
- spaCy Version Used: 2.2.3
- Environment Information: Conda

Comment: will  removing  extra space between string work for u  ????

Comment: Yes, removing extra space between the string works. But sometimes we may accidentally enter extra spaces. So in such cases, the code should works. (i.e the phrase matcher should match if there is single space or more than one space between the specified words).

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
re.sub(' +',' ', "barack    obama")

#op
'barack obama'
```

refereing to the docs https://spacy.io/api/phrasematcher

```
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("OBAMA", None, nlp("Barack Obama"))

doc = nlp("Barack Obama urges Congress to find courage to defend his healthcare reforms")
matches = matcher(doc)

#op
[(7732777389095836264, 0, 2)]
```

but  when there is a multiple space between the string it will return empty list. i.e there is multiple space between barack obama

```
doc = nlp("Barack   Obama urges Congress to find courage to defend his 
healthcare reforms")
print(matcher(doc))
#op
[]
```

to Solve this, i thought of removing extra space from the given string

```
string_=  'Barack   Obama urges Congress to find courage to defend his healthcare reforms'

space_removed_string = re.sub(' +',' ', string_)

#now passing the string in model
doc = nlp(space_removed_string)
print(matcher(doc))

#op
[(7732777389095836264, 0, 2)]
```

Comment: Please add some more of an explanation to your code-only answer to improve its quality as it otherwise appears correct.

Comment: If a term from the terms list matches in the given sentences. The Phrase Matcher returns the matched string. The Phrase Matcher works if the term in terms list, as well as the sentence, has a single space between "Barack Obama". Sometimes we may accidentally enter extra spaces in the sentences. So in such cases, the code should works. (i.e the phrase matcher should match if there is single space or more than one space between the terms). You can refer this link https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#phrasematcher

Comment: @qaiser I tried your updated solution and it works fine without affecting the performance of the code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That is a much better answer. Thanks for listening to feedback.